# Call a method as a R-Value

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

I am reading a book about the new features of C++11, 14 and 17. In the chapter about `move`-semantics the author uses the following class as an example:

```
class DataObject {
public:
  DataObject(int n, int v): data_(new int[n]), size_(n) {
    std::fill(data_, data_ + size_, v);
  }
  virtual ~DataObject() {
    delete[] data_;
  }
  ... //copy constructor, assignment operator

private:
  int* data_;
  int size_;
}
```

Now, he introduces the overloaded method `getData()` which returns `data_` as a
L- or a R-Value:

```
//For L-Value
int* getData() const& {
  int* result(new int[size_]);
  copy(data_, data_ + size_, result);
  return result;
}

//For R-Value
int* getData() && {
  return data_;
  data_ = nullptr;
  size_ = 0;
}
```

The following examples are shown afterwards:

```
DataObject do(4, 10);
int* data1 = do.getData();
int* data2 = DataObject(5, 20).getData();
```

I have a problem with the R-Value `getData()` method; it does not make sense to me. We return `data_` and then we set `data_` to `nullptr`... but the function was left already with `return data_`. How can `data_ = nullptr` and `size_ = 0` can ever be executed? And even if they would be executed, the destructor would try to delete `nullptr` when `DataObject(5,20)` gets out of scope.

**Question**:
Is there an error or am I misunderstanding something? How the two lines can be executed after we leave the function?

Comment: Seems like a terrible book based on what you've posted

Comment: One of your misconceptions was answered by @tobi303. Also your question has nothing to do with move semantics. About the 2 lines after the return statement, I've never seen that before and I highly doubt it will be executed (please correct if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your premise is wrong (emphasize mine):

> The introduces the overloaded method getData() which **returns data_ as
>   a L- or a R-Value**

The `&` and `&&` refer to the object on which you invoke the method (just as the `const` does in that place) not the return type. And thats what the example is demonstrating:

```
DataObject do(4, 10);
int* data1 = do.getData();
//           ^ this is a l-value

int* data2 = DataObject(5, 20).getData();
//                ^ this is a r-value
```

Now to your actual question:

> We return data_ and then we set data_ to nullptr... but the function
>   was left already with return data_

You are completely right, and that code is nonsense. There is no way the statements after the return will ever be executed.

PS: Usually I avoid spreading my opinions on books and the like, but in this case I have to tell you that it is a really bad example and you should stay away from that book.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is asking. He is asking about how the 2 lines after the return statement is executed.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo hm I guess you are right, I actually wasnt sure if I understood the question ;)

Comment: This is also useful information since OP is misunderstanding the ref-qualifiers

Comment: @M.M yep I edited to make my misunderstanding clear and hopefully also OPs

Comment: That's right. I was not aware of the fact that & and && refere to the object.

Comment: @Varius actually after reading your question again I finally understood it ;). updated the answer

Comment: note that `int* data2 = DataObject(5, 20).getData();` will just cause a dangling pointer, since the `getData()&&` contains this bug which OP identified

Comment: @M.M is there a straightforward way to fix it ? Imho it is just a super bad example

Comment: @tobi303 How about `class DataObject : public std::vector<int> {};` :) But in all seriousness, there are too many things that needs to be fixed, IMO the only valid suggestion is to ditch the book.

Comment: @PasserBy no way. how about `typedef std::vector<int> DataObject;` ;)

Comment: I guess the intent was `auto temp = data_; data_ = nullptr; size = 0; return temp;`

Comment: @M.M I have to admit that only now I understood it completely, unfortunately I am too tired atm to improve the answer, maybe i will do it at some point...

Comment: Ok, it's similar to creating a constant object `const DataObject d(2, 10);`. It cannot execute a method `int getSize();` but it could execute `int getSize() const;`. It makes sense now with the `&&` in the `getData()`. But another confusion arised: I modified the `main()` function to
 `int* data2 = nullptr;
 {
    data2 = DataObject(5, 20).getData();
 }
std::cout << *data2 << std::endl;`

I do not get any exceptions the output is "20". But the temporal object `Data=bject(5, 20)` is destroyed after the bracket is closed, and so is `data_`. How can I dereference it afterwards?

Comment: @Varius you dont get an exception in that case, but it is undefined behaviour, ie anything can happen